# Rails ActiveRecord sum of users voted?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The result I want is simply the number of users voted for rateable_id = '3'?

Example: As you can see in my table rates, rater_id: 1 and rater_id: 8 have voted for rateable_id = 3. This makes 2 users.

My question is how to display that in view?

This is in my ranking_controller.rb:

```
class RankingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @rankings = Rate.find(:all)
  end
end
```

This is in my table rates:

```
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 11
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 12
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 13
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 14
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 15
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 16
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 17
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 18
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 19
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 25
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 26
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 27
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 28
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 29
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use it as below:

```
@raters_count = Rate.select(:rater_id).where(rateable_id: 3, rateable_type: 'Bboy' ).distinct.count
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this.

One would be

```
@ranking_count = Rate.where(rateable_id: 3).pluck(:rater_id).uniq.count
```

Comment: I did this and it displays number of rateable_id: 3. Which is 10. What I need is to display how many rater_ids voted for rateable_id: 3? Which is 2! How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Or this

```
@ratings = Rate.group("dimension, rateable_id").select("rateable_id, dimension, count(rater_id) as rate_count")
#=> SELECT rateable_id, dimension,count(rater_id) as rate_count FROM rates GROUP BY dimension, rateable_id
```

Then

```
@ratings.each do |rating| 
    rating.dimension
    rating.rateable_id
    rating.rate_count
end
```

Obviously modifiable to fit your needs but something like this should suffice. Also more flexible than your original question since your question differs from you code. Your question only wants to handle 1 `rateable_id` but your code loads all `Rate` so I answered based on retrieving all `Rate` objects with a method for `rate_count` based on dimension.

A more expansive method might be

```
 @ratings = Rate.group("dimension, rateable_id, rateable_type").select("rateable_id, dimension,rateable_type, count(rater_id) as rate_count, avg(stars) as stars")
  #=> SELECT rateable_id, dimension,rateable_type,count(rater_id) as rate_count, avg(stars) as stars FROM rates GROUP BY dimension, rateable_id,rateable_type
```

Then

```
@ratings.each do |rating| 
    rating.dimension
    rating.rateable_id
    rating.rateable_type
    rating.rate_count
    rating.stars
end
```

This will give you access to the number of ratings and the average number of stars based on a rates grouped by `dimension`, `rateable_id` and `rateable_type`

This should return something along these lines (psuedo) based on your output above

```
[<Rate dimension:"foundation",rateable_id:3,rateable_type:"Bboy",rate_count:2, stars:3>,
 <Rate dimension:"originality",rateable_id:3,rateable_type:"Bboy",rate_count:2, stars:3>,
 <Rate dimension:"dynamics",rateable_id:3,rateable_type:"Bboy",rate_count:2, stars:3>,
 <Rate dimension:"execution",rateable_id:3,rateable_type:"Bboy",rate_count:2, stars:3>,
 <Rate dimension:"battle",rateable_id:3,rateable_type:"Bboy",rate_count:2, stars:3>,
 <Rate dimension:"foundation",rateable_id:5,rateable_type:"Bboy",rate_count:1, stars:5>,
 <Rate dimension:"originality",rateable_id:5,rateable_type:"Bboy",rate_count:1, stars:5>,
 <Rate dimension:"dynamics",rateable_id:5,rateable_type:"Bboy",rate_count:1, stars:5>,
 <Rate dimension:"battle",rateable_id:5,rateable_type:"Bboy",rate_count:1, stars:5>]
```